# A particular syntactic construct in R

Tags: r, syntax

In

```
 Orders1=Orders[Datecreated<floor_date(send_Date,unit='week',week_start = 7)-weeks(PrevWeek),
                      .(Previous_Sales=sum(Sales)),
                      by=.(Category,send_Date=floor_date(send_Date,unit='week',week_start = 7))]
```

What does the `.` in `.(Previous_Sales=sum(Sales))` mean? This is some syntactic nuance with which I am not familiar.

Also, what does `by=.(Category,s....`
Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the `.` is similar to calling a `list` in `data.table`.  It is creating a summarised output column

```
.(Previous_Sales=sum(Sales))
```

Or with `list`

```
list(Previous_Sales=sum(Sales))
```

In `dplyr`,  similar syntax would be

```
 summarise(Previous_Sales = sum(Sales))
```

and for creating a column/modifying an existing column usee

```
 mutate(Previous_Sales = sum(Sales))
```

With `data.table`, updating/creating a column is done with `:=`

```
 Previous_Sales := sum(Sales)
```

Similarly, the `by` also would be a `list` of column names

```
by = list(Category, send_Date=floor_date(send_Date,unit='week',week_start = 7)
```

which we can also use

```
by = .(Category, send_Date=floor_date(send_Date,unit='week',week_start = 7)
```

---

In the context of `data.table`, the syntax is consistent in the order

```
  dt[i, j, by]
```

where `i`, is the place where we specify the row condition for subsetting the rows, `j`, we apply functions on column/columns and `by` the grouping columns.  Using a simple example with `iris`

```
as.data.table(iris)[Sepal.Length < 5, .(Sum = sum(Sepal.Width)), by = Species]
```

the `i` is `Sepal.Length < 5` it selects only those rows meeting that condition to `sum` the 'Sepal.Width' (in that rows), and as the `by` option is provided, it will do the `sum` of 'Sepal.Width' for each 'Species' resulting in a 3 row (here there are 3 unique 'Species').  We can also do this without the `i` option by doing the subsetting in `j` itself

```
as.data.table(iris)[, .(Sum = sum(Sepal.Width[Sepal.Length < 5])), by = Species]
```

With `summarise`ation, both of these are okay, but if we do an assignment (`:=`), it would different

```
 as.data.table(iris)[Sepal.Length < 5,  Sum := sum(Sepal.Width), by = Species]
```

This would create a column 'Sum' and fills the `sum` values only where the 'Sepal.Length < 5`and all other row elements will be`NA`.  If we do the second option

```
as.data.table(iris)[,  Sum := sum(Sepal.Width[Sepal.Length < 5]), by = Species]
```

there won't be any NA element because it is subsetting within the `j` to create a single `sum` value for each 'Species'

Comment: Thank you. The statement starts with Orders1=Orders[<condition on rows>,<condition on columns>, by = ...] In the context of this statement, I don't quite understand your answer. How can summarise be used without a group_by? The "." seems to be referring to something..To what list are you referring? How does it make sense in the context of the statement?

Comment: @user2371765 in `data.table`, the syntax would be `dt[i, j, by]` where `i` refers to row indexing either with a logical condition for subsetting rows or for joining with another ddataset, `j` is where the summarise `.(...)`or assignment (`:=`) syntax is used and `by` is for grouping variables.  with joins, there would be `on` as well

Comment: @user2371765 Regarding `list`, data.frame, data.table/tbl_df etc are all lists with elements (columns) of equal lengths.  `summarise` can be used without group_by as well.  i.e. `iris %>% summarise(Sum = sum(Sepal.Length))`

Comment: Since in place of j there is .(Previous Sales=sum(Sales)) does that mean that Orders1 is a single row since sum(Sales) is a number? Also, what is the significance of "by" in a way similar to how "by" in a full join indicates the list of columns on which the full join takes place? Can you please explain in the context of my example?

Comment: @user2371765 In your example, there is no join, you are specifying the `i` condition `Datecreated<floor_date(send_Date,unit='week',week_start = 7)-weeks(PrevWeek)` i.e. only for those selected rows that satisfy the condition, the 'Sales' elements are added `sum(Sales)` and this is done for each combination of groups `Category,send_Date=floor_date(send_Date,unit='week',week_start = 7)` and since `sum` output is a single element, you will get one row for each group combination

Comment: @user2371765 Consider iris dataset, `as.data.table(iris)[Sepal.Length < 5, .(Sum = sum(Sepal.Width)), by = Species]`. Here, it is adding the 'Sepal.Width' where the `Sepal.Length` elements are less 5 for each 'Species'.  Which can be also written as `as.data.table(iris)[, .(Sum = sum(Sepal.Width[Sepal.Length < 5])), by = Species]`

Comment: Thank you. Can you include your above explanation in the answer? I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Is the below equivalent to your iris example?  iris%>%filter(Sepal.Length<5)%>%group_by(Species)%>%summarise(s=sum(Sepal.Width))

Comment: @user2371765 Yes, or you can also do `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(s = sum(Sepal.Width[Sepal.Length < 5]))`

Comment: I added some more details in the post

Comment: I understand the role of "Category" in by = .(Category, send_Date=floor_date(send_Date,unit='week',week_start = 7) (So sendDate is a Sunday). But what is the role of send_Date? It is the result of an expression, and, in particular, there might be values of sendDate in the original data table that might not fall on Sundays. So are these sendDates not included in any of the groups?

Comment: @user2371765 based on the expression, you are flooring the 'date' by 'week' and use that as a grouping variable. It would be good if you can post as a new question as the details are not clear

Comment: What you write is the answer. Thank you. The details are in the question. There's nothing more to this.. So the flooring and the use as the grouping variable are both happening in the same statement. It is C-like syntax for. In C, if I do if (a=2) <do something> a is set to 2 and then the thing is done. It is like killing two birds in one stone.